# Sendgrid stopped sending emails via Expressjs

Tags: reactjs, express, sendgrid, nodemailer

This is a very weird issue, but I don't know what is wrong with my app. I haven't committed any change, yet for some reason the app stopped sending emails, and shows an `POST error: cannot find route api/example`

I have a React component that has a email field and a button. When clicked, the button triggers a function:

```
sendMail() {
if (this.state.currentEmail !== "") {
  let lastAtPos = this.state.currentEmail.lastIndexOf("@");
  let lastDotPos = this.state.currentEmail.lastIndexOf(".");

  if (
    !(
      lastAtPos < lastDotPos &&
      lastAtPos > 0 &&
      this.state.currentEmail.indexOf("@@") === -1 &&
      lastDotPos > 2 &&
      this.state.currentEmail.length - lastDotPos > 2
    )
  ) {
    this.setState({ error: "Please, provide your real e-mail address!" });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      sending: true,
      buttonText: ""
    });

    let data = {
      email: this.state.currentEmail
    };

    axios
      .post("/api/subscribers", data)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ isSent: true }, this.resetForm());
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Message not sent");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The ExpressJS route:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body;

    let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "Zoho",
      port: 465,
      auth: {
        user: creds.USER,
        pass: creds.PASS
      }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
      from: "EMAIL",
      to: "EMAIL",
      subject: "New user subscribed via DOMAIN",
      html: `<p>${data.email}</p>`
    };

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        res.send(error);
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        res.send("Success");
      }
      smtpTransport.close();
    });

    const msg = {
      to: data.email,
      from: "DOMAIN <EMAIL>",
      templateId: "TEMPLATE ID",
      subject: "TEXT",
      text: "TEXT"
    };

    //Send Email
    try {
      sgMail.send(msg);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

As I said, this used to work fine a week ago, until I started noticing that emails are not being sent. I debugged, and all I am getting is the `"Message not sent"` error from the client and the `POST error cannot find api/example` route error (and an HTML piece of code).

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that should be generating that POST.

Is it possible that you made a change to your react application's SRC but did not run a new build?

I know I've done this a few times, making a change to the client side of the application without generating a new build and putting it into my express app's static folder.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was that I enabled the 2 factor Auth for Zoho, and wasn't receiving any error of not successful login attempt! Wasted hours until I found the cause...